# Actionscript VerifyError: The ABC data is corrupt, attempt to read out of bounds

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, compiler-errors

Getting a VerifyError using the `TweenMax` lib when calling `TweenMax.to`. This error doesn't seem to be specific to TweenMax (we've found other people having errors with unrelated code). Perhaps someone has some insight into what this error means and what could be causing it.

**Edit**

Seems like it's something to do with Anonymous functions: https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-14054

Here's the error:

```
VerifyError: Error #1107: The ABC data is corrupt, attempt to read out of bounds. at global$init()
```

And the full error:

```
verify global$init()
                        stack:
                        scope: 
                         locals: global 
  0:getlocal0
                        stack: global
                        scope: 
                         locals: global 
  1:pushscope
                        stack:
                        scope: global 
                         locals: global 

2:debugfile
"D:\Projects\Mattel\PollyPocket\CutantsSite_PollyRelaunch\3_project-build\programming_teaser\code\classes;gs;TweenMax.as"
                        stack:
                        scope: global 
                         locals: global 
  5:debugline 387
                        stack:
                        scope: global 
                         locals: global 
  8:findpropstrict {gs}::TweenMax
                        stack: global
                        scope: global 
                         locals: global 
  11:getlex 2
                        stack: global Object$?
                        scope: global 
                         locals: global 
  13:pushscope
                        stack: global
                        scope: global Object$ 
                         locals: global 
  14:getlex 16
                        stack: global gs::TweenLite$?
                        scope: global Object$ 
                         locals: global 
  16:pushscope
                        stack: global
                        scope: global Object$ gs::TweenLite$ 
                         locals: global 
  17:getlex 16
                        stack: global gs::TweenLite$?
                        scope: global Object$ gs::TweenLite$ 
                         locals: global 
  19:newclass gs::TweenMax$cinit()
VerifyError: Error #1107: The ABC data is corrupt, attempt to read out of bounds.
      at global$init()

at
mattel.pollypocket.cutantssite.site.page.mycutants::CutantButtonWorldGroup/addedToStage()[D:\Projects\Mattel\PollyPocket\CutantsSite_PollyRelaunch\3_project-build\programming_teaser\code\classes\mattel\pollypocket\cutantssite\site\page\mycutants\CutantButtonWorldGroup.as:118]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found a bug in the compiler. The best what you can do now is try figuring out what caused the bug and file a bugreport at bugs.adobe.com

As a side note. It is very rare to find nowadays bugs in the Java compiler for instance. The ActionScript compiler has still a lot of issues with strange control flow etc.